# Configuring authManager for Custom Yii2 Template

Tags: templates, yii, yii2, migration, rbac

I'm trying to perform a RBAC migration following [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) documentation except I'm using a custom template, not the basic or advanced (though I believe it's based on basic)

So my problem is, I'm not sure where exactly this code to configure the authManager should be placed

```
'components' => [
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager'
```

I guess my underlying question is why exactly does this code to configure the authManager get placed in a specific file (config/console.php and config/web.php for basic template) because if I understand that, I ought to be able to find or create the file I need to for my template. I have a config folder in my template, but no console or web file within it.

Hopefully this question isn't overly specific.

Comment: you should have a  directory config.  with main.php (or main-local.php) or web.php  ..

Comment: So I don't seem to have those files, maybe the same/code logic is placed elsewhere in the template. Would simply creating a file within my config directory with that code meant to configure the authManager work?

Comment: In advanced  template  the config dir is placed in yourproject/backend/config , yourproject/frontend/config, yourproject/common/config .. in basic template  in placed in yourproject/config and is named  web.php

Comment: Anyway  in yourproject/web/ directory take a look at the index.php  in this file you should find a ref  for main.php  or web.php  .. then search in the dir suggested  by this ref

Comment: if it is a custom template you should provide the link to it on github most probably so that the file structure is clear.